# JSON Array iteration using For Loop stopped at last index

Tags: javascript, json, p5.js

I'm creating a canvas using p5.js and Marine Weather JSON file.
I'm setting for loops to iterate through the array of values from JSON file (e.g. for the length of the loop, change colour based on the values of each indices).
The for loop seems to only show the value from last index.

I have 6 things that I'm using for loop:

1. Change alpha value depending on air temperature & water
   temperature from JSON divided by given number.
2. Draw random circles until loop ends for x number of times, where x = humidity value from JSON.
3. Change circle colour from array when index of colour array matches index of JSON array that I have created.
4. Draw sine wave with amplitude value from wave height & wind speed value of JSON.

At the moment, when I test using variable and for loop, everything seems to freeze at last index value. If I comment out the for loop and give the index a fixed value instead of variable, the sine waves animates (still only of last index value).
Circles form randomly if I comment out all for loop related part, however they disappear and reform too quickly.

I'll add the JSON in CSS part.

```js
let weather;

let xspacing = 15; // Distance between each horizontal location
let waveWidth; // Width of entire wave
let theta = 0.0; // Start angle at 0
let amplitude = 25; // Height of wave
let period = 1000.0; // How many pixels before the wave repeats
let dx; // Value for incrementing x
let yvalues; // Using an array to store height values for the wave

function setup() {
  //set up a canvas that's size depends on the browser size
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  colorMode(HSB);

  waveWidth = width + 16;
  dx = (TWO_PI / period) * xspacing;
  yvalues = new Array(floor(waveWidth / xspacing));
}

function draw() {
  let warmth = color(50, 100, 100); //rgb 255, 215, 0
  let upper = color(0, 100, 65); //rgb 165, 0, 0
  let lower = color(234, 100, 31); //rgb 0, 8, 80

  let start = color(50, 2, 100); //rgb 255, 254, 249
  let mid = color(50, 100, 100); //rgb 255, 212, 0
  let end = color(49, 100, 13); //rbg 33, 27, 0

  let mixer = [];
  mixer[0] = start;
  mixer[1] = lerpColor(start, mid, 0.099);
  mixer[2] = lerpColor(start, mid, 0.198);
  mixer[3] = lerpColor(start, mid, 0.297);
  mixer[4] = lerpColor(start, mid, 0.396);
  mixer[5] = lerpColor(start, mid, 0.495);
  mixer[6] = lerpColor(start, mid, 0.594);
  mixer[7] = lerpColor(start, mid, 0.693);
  mixer[8] = lerpColor(start, mid, 0.792);
  mixer[9] = lerpColor(start, mid, 0.891);
  mixer[10] = lerpColor(start, mid, 0.99);
  mixer[11] = mid;
  mixer[12] = lerpColor(mid, end, 0.099);
  mixer[13] = lerpColor(mid, end, 0.198);
  mixer[14] = lerpColor(mid, end, 0.297);
  mixer[15] = lerpColor(mid, end, 0.396);
  mixer[16] = lerpColor(mid, end, 0.495);
  mixer[17] = lerpColor(mid, end, 0.594);
  mixer[18] = lerpColor(mid, end, 0.693);
  mixer[19] = lerpColor(mid, end, 0.792);
  mixer[20] = lerpColor(mid, end, 0.891);
  mixer[21] = lerpColor(mid, end, 0.99);
  mixer[23] = end;

  //background colour of canvas
  background(0, 28, 122);

  fill(0, 100, 65);
  noStroke();
  rect(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight / 2);
  //upper half of canvas representing air temperature
  for (let a = 0; a < weather.hours.length; a++) {
    fill(47, 100, 100, (weather.hours[a].airTemperature - 27) / 10);
    noStroke();
    rect(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight / 2);
  }

  //lower half of canvas representing water temperature
  fill(234, 100, 31);
  noStroke();
  rect(0, windowHeight / 2, windowWidth, windowHeight / 2);

  for (let w = 0; w < weather.hours.length; w++) {
    fill(47, 100, 100, (weather.hours[w].waterTemperature - 28) / 20);
    noStroke();
    rect(0, windowHeight / 2, windowWidth, windowHeight / 2);
  }

  //translucent circles with random sizes to form on random locations
  for (let h = 0; h > weather.hours.length; h++) {
    let humidityCircle = weather.hours[h].humidity;
    for (let hc = 0; hc > humidityCircle; hc++) {
      fill(255, 255, 255, 127.5);
      noStroke();
      circle(random(windowWidth), random(windowHeight / 2), random((windowWidth / 18) + 15));
    }
  }

  calcWindWave();
  renderWindWave();

  calcWaveWave();
  renderWaveWave();

  //middle large circle
  for (let t = 0; t < weather.hours.length; t++) {
    fill(mixer[weather.hours[t].time]);
    noStroke();
    circle(windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2, windowHeight / 3.5);
  }
}

function calcWindWave() {
  //change amplitude using windSpeed
  //Increment theta (try different values for 'angular velocity' here)
  theta += 0.02;

  //For every x value, calculate a y value with sine function
  let x = theta;
  let wsAmplitude;

  for (let ws = 0; ws < weather.hours.length; ws++) {
    wsAmplitude = weather.hours[ws].windSpeed * amplitude;
    for (i = 0; i < yvalues.length; i++) {
      yvalues[i] = sin(x) * wsAmplitude;
      x += dx;
    }
  }
}

function calcWaveWave() {
  //change amplitude using waveHeight
  //Increment theta (try different values for 'angular velocity' here)
  theta += 0.05;

  // For every x value, calculate a y value with sine function
  let x = theta;
  let whAmplitude;

  for (let wh = 0; wh < weather.hours.length; wh++) {
    whAmplitude = weather.hours[wh].waveHeight * amplitude;
    for (let i = 0; i < yvalues.length; i++) {
      yvalues[i] = sin(x) * whAmplitude;
      x += dx;
    }
  }
}

function renderWindWave() {
  noStroke();
  fill(255);
  //A simple way to draw the wave with an ellipse at each location
  for (let x = 0; x < yvalues.length; x++) {
    ellipse(x * xspacing, height / 2 + yvalues[x], 3, 3);
  }
}

function renderWaveWave() {
  noStroke();
  fill(255);
  //A simple way to draw the wave with an ellipse at each location
  for (let x = 0; x < yvalues.length; x++) {
    ellipse(x * xspacing, height / 2 - yvalues[x], 3, 3);
    print(yvalues.x);
  }
}

function preload() {
  weather = {
    "hours": [{
        "airTemperature": 27.65,
        "humidity": 70.8,
        "time": 0,
        "waterTemperature": 29.28,
        "waveHeight": 1.62,
        "windSpeed": 3.26
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.67,
        "humidity": 70.9,
        "time": 1,
        "waterTemperature": 29.35,
        "waveHeight": 1.7,
        "windSpeed": 3.1
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.7,
        "humidity": 71,
        "time": 2,
        "waterTemperature": 29.31,
        "waveHeight": 1.78,
        "windSpeed": 2.94
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.72,
        "humidity": 71.1,
        "time": 3,
        "waterTemperature": 29.14,
        "waveHeight": 1.86,
        "windSpeed": 2.78
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.67,
        "humidity": 71.8,
        "time": 4,
        "waterTemperature": 28.93,
        "waveHeight": 1.86,
        "windSpeed": 2.65
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.62,
        "humidity": 72.5,
        "time": 5,
        "waterTemperature": 28.8,
        "waveHeight": 1.86,
        "windSpeed": 2.53
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.57,
        "humidity": 73.2,
        "time": 6,
        "waterTemperature": 28.7,
        "waveHeight": 1.86,
        "windSpeed": 2.4
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.47,
        "humidity": 73.51,
        "time": 7,
        "waterTemperature": 28.63,
        "waveHeight": 1.85,
        "windSpeed": 2.24
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.38,
        "humidity": 73.82,
        "time": 8,
        "waterTemperature": 28.58,
        "waveHeight": 1.83,
        "windSpeed": 2.09
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.28,
        "humidity": 74.13,
        "time": 9,
        "waterTemperature": 28.54,
        "waveHeight": 1.82,
        "windSpeed": 1.93
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.19,
        "humidity": 74.1,
        "time": 10,
        "waterTemperature": 28.51,
        "waveHeight": 1.8,
        "windSpeed": 1.83
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.11,
        "humidity": 74.06,
        "time": 11,
        "waterTemperature": 28.48,
        "waveHeight": 1.78,
        "windSpeed": 1.74
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.02,
        "humidity": 74.03,
        "time": 12,
        "waterTemperature": 28.46,
        "waveHeight": 1.76,
        "windSpeed": 1.64
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.02,
        "humidity": 73.98,
        "time": 13,
        "waterTemperature": 28.45,
        "waveHeight": 1.74,
        "windSpeed": 1.69
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.02,
        "humidity": 73.94,
        "time": 14,
        "waterTemperature": 28.43,
        "waveHeight": 1.72,
        "windSpeed": 1.74
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.02,
        "humidity": 73.89,
        "time": 15,
        "waterTemperature": 28.42,
        "waveHeight": 1.7,
        "windSpeed": 1.79
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.02,
        "humidity": 73.01,
        "time": 16,
        "waterTemperature": 28.42,
        "waveHeight": 1.69,
        "windSpeed": 1.92
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.03,
        "humidity": 72.13,
        "time": 17,
        "waterTemperature": 28.42,
        "waveHeight": 1.67,
        "windSpeed": 2.04
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.04,
        "humidity": 71.25,
        "time": 18,
        "waterTemperature": 28.54,
        "waveHeight": 1.66,
        "windSpeed": 2.17
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.09,
        "humidity": 70.52,
        "time": 19,
        "waterTemperature": 28.74,
        "waveHeight": 1.65,
        "windSpeed": 2.35
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.15,
        "humidity": 69.8,
        "time": 20,
        "waterTemperature": 29.04,
        "waveHeight": 1.65,
        "windSpeed": 2.53
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.21,
        "humidity": 69.08,
        "time": 21,
        "waterTemperature": 29.39,
        "waveHeight": 1.64,
        "windSpeed": 2.71
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.32,
        "humidity": 71.12,
        "time": 22,
        "waterTemperature": 29.72,
        "waveHeight": 1.63,
        "windSpeed": 3.23
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.44,
        "humidity": 73.16,
        "time": 23,
        "waterTemperature": 30,
        "waveHeight": 1.63,
        "windSpeed": 3.74
      }
    ],
    "meta": {
      "cost": 1,
      "dailyQuota": 50,
      "end": "2018-07-01 23:59",
      "lat": 9.933917,
      "lng": -132.038444,
      "params": [
        "airTemperature",
        "humidity",
        "waterTemperature",
        "waveHeight",
        "windSpeed"
      ],
      "requestCount": 3,
      "source": "sg",
      "start": "2018-07-01 00:00"
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- PLEASE NO CHANGES BELOW THIS LINE (UNTIL I SAY SO) -->
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="libraries/p5.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="p5js-temp-Restless_Sea9110872967160478905.js"></script>
  <!-- OK, YOU CAN MAKE CHANGES BELOW THIS LINE AGAIN -->

  <!-- This line removes any default padding and style.
       You might only need one of these values set. -->
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have lots of `for` loops in the code, which one is the problem? Can you simplify the example and remove code that's not relevant to the question?

Comment: Why are you creating all those different arrays, instead of just using the array from the JSON?

Comment: @Barmar So basically all of them are only returning last index value from the array. And because without bringing the JSON in arrays like that, the for loop didn't return anything at all.

Comment: Actually, it seems like you're never even using those arrays. You fill in the `humidity`, `hour`, and `windSpeed` arrays by copying from `weather.hours`, but never use them.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry I misunderstood what you meant. I fixed my code by removing the arrays and getting the array length straight from JSON, but still everything’s stuck on the last index and the circles are not forming at all.

Comment: You still haven't clarified which of the many `for` loops is the one that's getting stuck.

Comment: Your code snippet has JSON in the CSS box. How is that supposed to work? Put it in the JavaScript so the code can execute.

Comment: @Barmar I have explained in my post that all the loops are stuck on last index, and so in the comment. Also I just moved it.

Comment: I tried running your snippet, nothing happens. It looks like it's missing the call to start it running.

Comment: Is this supposed to be animation? You have nothing that delays any of the changes, so everything happens all at once.

Comment: And the final result is whatever the last iteration of the loops does.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah it’s supposed to be animation. Also the thing is that if I remove the for loop of middle circle and put in random number into mixer[ ], both the sine waves animate (still only last index value).

Comment: @Barmar  +) Otherwise the sine waves are stuck without moving at all. Which is very strange because the middle circle has nothing to do with the sine waves. So it should still animate.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with p5.js, if it's supposed to be animating I don't know the answer. Hopefully someone who knows p5 better will arrive.

Comment: @Barmar I just saw your edit. I originally have a separate JSON file that I loaded onto my p5.js. Anyways thank you for your help.

Comment: How the data gets loaded is not relevant to the question. I did that so the code can execute here, since we can't load your file.

Answer (score 1):

You (like many others) have missed out the structural concept of p5 library. Among other structural functions *draw()* is looping forever (unless you stop it) so you don't want to create own loops inside of it.
Although I dont understand what the desirable result should be, i'll throw you some guidelines:

```js
let clicked=false;  //this is for start/stop animation
let weather;

let xspacing = 15; // Distance between each horizontal location
let waveWidth; // Width of entire wave
let theta = 0.0; // Start angle at 0
let amplitude = 25; // Height of wave
let period = 1000.0; // How many pixels before the wave repeats
let dx; // Value for incrementing x
let yvalues; // Using an array to store height values for the wave

/* counters from inner loops */
let t = w = h = a = 0;

/* all the looping variables */
let warmth,
 upper,
 lower,
 start,
 mid,
 end;
/* array */
let mixer = [];

 /*******************************************************************
* P5 preload 
*
* Load images, data etc. Waits for any async is ended.
********************************************************************/
function preload() {
  weather = {
    "hours": [{
        "airTemperature": 27.65,
        "humidity": 70.8,
        "time": 0,
        "waterTemperature": 29.28,
        "waveHeight": 1.62,
        "windSpeed": 3.26
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.67,
        "humidity": 70.9,
        "time": 1,
        "waterTemperature": 29.35,
        "waveHeight": 1.7,
        "windSpeed": 3.1
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.7,
        "humidity": 71,
        "time": 2,
        "waterTemperature": 29.31,
        "waveHeight": 1.78,
        "windSpeed": 2.94
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.72,
        "humidity": 71.1,
        "time": 3,
        "waterTemperature": 29.14,
        "waveHeight": 1.86,
        "windSpeed": 2.78
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.67,
        "humidity": 71.8,
        "time": 4,
        "waterTemperature": 28.93,
        "waveHeight": 1.86,
        "windSpeed": 2.65
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.62,
        "humidity": 72.5,
        "time": 5,
        "waterTemperature": 28.8,
        "waveHeight": 1.86,
        "windSpeed": 2.53
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.57,
        "humidity": 73.2,
        "time": 6,
        "waterTemperature": 28.7,
        "waveHeight": 1.86,
        "windSpeed": 2.4
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.47,
        "humidity": 73.51,
        "time": 7,
        "waterTemperature": 28.63,
        "waveHeight": 1.85,
        "windSpeed": 2.24
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.38,
        "humidity": 73.82,
        "time": 8,
        "waterTemperature": 28.58,
        "waveHeight": 1.83,
        "windSpeed": 2.09
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.28,
        "humidity": 74.13,
        "time": 9,
        "waterTemperature": 28.54,
        "waveHeight": 1.82,
        "windSpeed": 1.93
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.19,
        "humidity": 74.1,
        "time": 10,
        "waterTemperature": 28.51,
        "waveHeight": 1.8,
        "windSpeed": 1.83
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.11,
        "humidity": 74.06,
        "time": 11,
        "waterTemperature": 28.48,
        "waveHeight": 1.78,
        "windSpeed": 1.74
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.02,
        "humidity": 74.03,
        "time": 12,
        "waterTemperature": 28.46,
        "waveHeight": 1.76,
        "windSpeed": 1.64
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.02,
        "humidity": 73.98,
        "time": 13,
        "waterTemperature": 28.45,
        "waveHeight": 1.74,
        "windSpeed": 1.69
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.02,
        "humidity": 73.94,
        "time": 14,
        "waterTemperature": 28.43,
        "waveHeight": 1.72,
        "windSpeed": 1.74
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.02,
        "humidity": 73.89,
        "time": 15,
        "waterTemperature": 28.42,
        "waveHeight": 1.7,
        "windSpeed": 1.79
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.02,
        "humidity": 73.01,
        "time": 16,
        "waterTemperature": 28.42,
        "waveHeight": 1.69,
        "windSpeed": 1.92
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.03,
        "humidity": 72.13,
        "time": 17,
        "waterTemperature": 28.42,
        "waveHeight": 1.67,
        "windSpeed": 2.04
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.04,
        "humidity": 71.25,
        "time": 18,
        "waterTemperature": 28.54,
        "waveHeight": 1.66,
        "windSpeed": 2.17
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.09,
        "humidity": 70.52,
        "time": 19,
        "waterTemperature": 28.74,
        "waveHeight": 1.65,
        "windSpeed": 2.35
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.15,
        "humidity": 69.8,
        "time": 20,
        "waterTemperature": 29.04,
        "waveHeight": 1.65,
        "windSpeed": 2.53
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.21,
        "humidity": 69.08,
        "time": 21,
        "waterTemperature": 29.39,
        "waveHeight": 1.64,
        "windSpeed": 2.71
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.32,
        "humidity": 71.12,
        "time": 22,
        "waterTemperature": 29.72,
        "waveHeight": 1.63,
        "windSpeed": 3.23
      },
      {
        "airTemperature": 27.44,
        "humidity": 73.16,
        "time": 23,
        "waterTemperature": 30,
        "waveHeight": 1.63,
        "windSpeed": 3.74
      }
    ],
    "meta": {
      "cost": 1,
      "dailyQuota": 50,
      "end": "2018-07-01 23:59",
      "lat": 9.933917,
      "lng": -132.038444,
      "params": [
        "airTemperature",
        "humidity",
        "waterTemperature",
        "waveHeight",
        "windSpeed"
      ],
      "requestCount": 3,
      "source": "sg",
      "start": "2018-07-01 00:00"
    }
  }
}
  
/*******************************************************************
* P5 setup 
* run once, use for initialisation.
*
* Create a canvas, show pictures, initialize arrays etc.
********************************************************************/
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  colorMode(HSB);

  waveWidth = width + 16;
  dx = (TWO_PI / period) * xspacing;
  yvalues = new Array(floor(waveWidth / xspacing));
 
 /*
  *  all the colors and mixer[] array should be
  *  initialized here as their values are not changed
  */
   warmth = color(50, 100, 100); //rgb 255, 215, 0
   upper = color(0, 100, 65); //rgb 165, 0, 0
   lower = color(234, 100, 31); //rgb 0, 8, 80

   start = color(50, 2, 100); //rgb 255, 254, 249
   mid = color(50, 100, 100); //rgb 255, 212, 0
   end = color(49, 100, 13); //rbg 33, 27, 0

  mixer[0] = start;
  mixer[1] = lerpColor(start, mid, 0.099);
  mixer[2] = lerpColor(start, mid, 0.198);
  mixer[3] = lerpColor(start, mid, 0.297);
  mixer[4] = lerpColor(start, mid, 0.396);
  mixer[5] = lerpColor(start, mid, 0.495);
  mixer[6] = lerpColor(start, mid, 0.594);
  mixer[7] = lerpColor(start, mid, 0.693);
  mixer[8] = lerpColor(start, mid, 0.792);
  mixer[9] = lerpColor(start, mid, 0.891);
  mixer[10] = lerpColor(start, mid, 0.99);
  mixer[11] = mid;
  mixer[12] = lerpColor(mid, end, 0.099);
  mixer[13] = lerpColor(mid, end, 0.198);
  mixer[14] = lerpColor(mid, end, 0.297);
  mixer[15] = lerpColor(mid, end, 0.396);
  mixer[16] = lerpColor(mid, end, 0.495);
  mixer[17] = lerpColor(mid, end, 0.594);
  mixer[18] = lerpColor(mid, end, 0.693);
  mixer[19] = lerpColor(mid, end, 0.792);
  mixer[20] = lerpColor(mid, end, 0.891);
  mixer[21] = lerpColor(mid, end, 0.95);
  mixer[22] = lerpColor(mid, end, 0.99);
  mixer[23] = end;

/* here you can change the speed of the animation */
  frameRate(3); 
}

/*******************************************************************
* P5 draw
* endless loop.
* 
* Do something visual with collected data.
* NB! This is already endless loop, do not create loops into it
********************************************************************/
function draw() {
  //background colour of canvas
  background(0, 28, 122);

  fill(0, 100, 65);
  noStroke();
  rect(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight / 2);

/* we are looping already, so you use variable a ... */
  //  for (let a = 0; a < weather.hours.length; a++) {
    fill(47, 100, 100, (weather.hours[a].airTemperature - 27) / 10);
    noStroke();
    rect(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight / 2);
/* ... and increase its value for the next loop */
  a++;
//  }

  fill(234, 100, 31);
  noStroke();
  rect(0, windowHeight / 2, windowWidth, windowHeight / 2);
//  for (let w = 0; w < weather.hours.length; w++) {
    fill(47, 100, 100, (weather.hours[w].waterTemperature - 28) / 20);
    noStroke();
    rect(0, windowHeight / 2, windowWidth, windowHeight / 2);
 w++;
//  }

  //translucent circles with random sizes to form on random locations

//  for (let h = 0; h > weather.hours.length; h++) {
    let humidityCircle = weather.hours[h].humidity;
    for (let hc = 0; hc < humidityCircle; hc++) {
      fill(255, 255, 255, 127.5);
      noStroke();
      ellipse(random(windowWidth), random(windowHeight / 2), random((windowWidth / 18) + 15));
    }
 h++;
//  }

  calcWindWave();
  renderWindWave();

  calcWaveWave();
  renderWaveWave();

  //middle large circle
//  for (let t = 0; t < weather.hours.length; t++) {
    fill(mixer[weather.hours[t].time]);
    noStroke();
    ellipse(windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2, windowHeight / 3.5);
 t++;
//  }

/* Also we have to check/change our counters
*  At this case all the counters will be initialized under same condition
*/
if(t>23)
 a = w = t = h = 0;
}

function calcWindWave() {
  //change amplitude using windSpeed
  //Increment theta (try different values for 'angular velocity' here)
  theta += 0.02;

  //For every x value, calculate a y value with sine function
  let x = theta;
  let wsAmplitude;

  for (let ws = 0; ws < weather.hours.length; ws++) {
    wsAmplitude = weather.hours[ws].windSpeed * amplitude;
    for (i = 0; i < yvalues.length; i++) {
      yvalues[i] = sin(x) * wsAmplitude;
      x += dx;
    }
  }
}

function calcWaveWave() {
  //change amplitude using waveHeight
  //Increment theta (try different values for 'angular velocity' here)
  theta += 0.05;

  // For every x value, calculate a y value with sine function
  let x = theta;
  let whAmplitude;

  for (let wh = 0; wh < weather.hours.length; wh++) {
    whAmplitude = weather.hours[wh].waveHeight * amplitude;
    for (let i = 0; i < yvalues.length; i++) {
      yvalues[i] = sin(x) * whAmplitude;
      x += dx;
    }
  }
}

function renderWindWave() {
  noStroke();
  fill(255);
  //A simple way to draw the wave with an ellipse at each location
  for (let x = 0; x < yvalues.length; x++) {
    ellipse(x * xspacing, height / 2 + yvalues[x], 3, 3);
  }
}

function renderWaveWave() {
  noStroke();
  fill(255);
  //A simple way to draw the wave with an ellipse at each location
  for (let x = 0; x < yvalues.length; x++) {
    ellipse(x * xspacing, height / 2 - yvalues[x], 3, 3);
//    print(yvalues.x);
  }
}
/*******************************************************************
* P5 mouseClicked
* 
* P5 event. I use it to start/stop the animation
********************************************************************/
mouseClicked = function() {
    if (mouseButton === LEFT) {
  clicked = !clicked;
  if(clicked){
   noLoop();
  }else{
   loop();
  }
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.js"></script>
```